Recreate image with GraphicsGrid
I am trying to recreate this image from a book:

Using GraphicsGrid I got this:

Code:
conf = {PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1.5}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   Ticks -> None, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> Black};
t1 = Table[1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p1 = ListLinePlot[t1, conf];
t2 = Table[
   Cos[3*x]/4 + 0.75 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p2 = ListLinePlot[t2, conf];
t3 = Table[x/4 + 0.1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p3 = ListLinePlot[t3, conf];
t4 = Table[
   Cos[3*x]/4 + 0.25 + x/4 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p4 = ListLinePlot[t4, conf];
t5 = Table[
   Piecewise[{{0.25 x + 0.1, x < 2}, {0.15 x + 0.75, x > 2}}] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p5 = ListLinePlot[t5, conf];
t6 = Table[
   UnitBox[x - 2]/2 + 0.5 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p6 = ListLinePlot[t6, conf];
t7 = Table[
   HeavisideTheta[-x + 2] + 0.25 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 
    4, .15}];
p7 = ListLinePlot[t7, conf];
t8 = Table[
   Piecewise[{{0.25, x < 2}, {0.3 x, x > 2}}] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p8 = ListLinePlot[t8, conf];
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}, {p5, p6}, {p7, p8}}]

How can I fix the labels so they match the original image?

conf = {PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1.5}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   Ticks -> None, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> Black};
t1 = Table[1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
t2 = Table[
   Cos[3*x]/4 + 0.75 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
t3 = Table[x/4 + 0.1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
t4 = Table[
   Cos[3*x]/4 + 0.25 + x/4 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
t5 = Table[
   Piecewise[{{0.25 x + 0.1, x < 2}, {0.15 x + 0.75, x > 2}}] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
t6 = Table[
   UnitBox[x - 2]/2 + 0.5 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
t7 = Table[
   HeavisideTheta[-x + 2] + 0.25 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 
    4, .15}];
t8 = Table[
   Piecewise[{{0.25, x < 2}, {0.3 x, x > 2}}] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];


MapThread[Labeled[
     ListLinePlot[#1, Evaluate@conf
      , ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 10}}
      , ImageSize -> Small
      ]
     , {#2 <> ")" <> #3, #4}, {#5, #6}, RotateLabel -> #7] &
   , {
    {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8}
    , Alphabet[][[1 ;; 8]]
    , {"RANDOM", "CYCLE + RANDOM", "TREND + RANDOM", 
     "TREND + CYCLE + RANDOM"
     , "TREND + NON-RANDOM", "RANDOM WITH IMPULSE", 
     "STEP CHANGE + RANDOM", "RANDOM FOLLOWED\nBY TREND"}
    , {"\nCONCENTRATION", "",  "\nCONCENTRATION", "", 
     "\nCONCENTRATION", "", "\nCONCENTRATION", ""}
    , ConstantArray[{Bottom, Left}, 8]
    , ConstantArray[Left, 8]
    , {True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False}
    }
   ] // Partition[#, 2] & // Grid




Cool! How can I set a specific font or font size to the labels?

Try: {Style[#2 <> ")" <> #3, Bold, 18, Red],   Style[#4, FontSlant -> Italic]} and set ImageSize -> Medium to avoid label position from deteriorating.

You can use Legended and Grid
conf =
  {PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1.5}},
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
   Ticks -> None,
   PlotStyle -> Black,
   AxesStyle -> Black};

co = Placed[Rotate[Style["CONCENTRATION", 8], 90 Degree], Left];


t1 = Table[1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p1 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t1, conf], {Placed[Style["(a) RANDOM", 10], Below], co}];

t2 = Table[Cos[3*x]/4 + 0.75 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p2 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t2, conf], {Placed[Style["(b) CYCLE + RANDOM", 10], Below]}];

t3 = Table[x/4 + 0.1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p3 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t3, conf], {Placed[Style["(c) TREND + RANDOM", 10], Below], co}];

t4 = Table[Cos[3*x]/4 + 0.25 + x/4 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p4 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t4, conf], {Placed[Style["(d) TREND + CYCLE + RANDOM", 10], Below]}];

t5 = Table[Piecewise[{{0.25 x + 0.1, x < 2}, {0.15 x + 0.75, x > 2}}] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p5 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t5, conf], {Placed[Style["(e) TREND + NON-RANDOM", 10], Below], co}];

t6 = Table[UnitBox[x - 2]/2 + 0.5 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p6 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t6, conf], {Placed[Style["(f) RANDOM WITH IMPULSE", 10], Below]}];

t7 = Table[HeavisideTheta[-x + 2] + 0.25 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p7 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t7, conf], {Placed[Style["(g) STEP CHANGE + RANDOM", 10], Below], co}];

t8 = Table[Piecewise[{{0.25, x < 2}, {0.3 x, x > 2}}] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 4, .15}];
p8 = Legended[ListLinePlot[t8, conf], {Placed[Style["(h) RANDOM FOLLOWED BY TREND", 10], Below]}];


Grid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}, {p5, p6}, {p7, p8}}, Spacings -> Scaled[.05]]


